# PostgreSQL installation on MSCS Windows Cluster

Tags: database, postgresql, cluster-computing, windows-clustering

Anyone had to install PostgreSQL on Windows Cluster using shared storage? If so, could you please advise on the installation steps. I know this is not the best approach but I'm running on Windows.

Comment: is it for your office requirement or your personal requirement. for your personal matter, try docker container. that's the easiest way

Comment: Unfortunately office requirement.